# Firebase deploy issue. Running command: npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, facebook-webhooks

Deploying 3 simple functions over firebase project to get started with and expecting their respective URLs after deploying but getting no url.

Here is the **code:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.helloWorldOne = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
response.send("Hello 1 from Firebase!");
});

exports.helloWorldTwo = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
response.send("Hello 2 from Firebase!");
});

exports.helloWorldThree = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) =>{
response.send("Hello 3 from Firebase!");
});
```

**Output:**

D:\IOT\DialogFlow\firebase functions>firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'fir-functions-22d02'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix ./functions/ run lint

> functions@ lint D:\IOT\DialogFlow\firebase functions\functions
>   eslint .

- functions: Finished running predeploy script.
  i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
- functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
  i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
- Deploy complete!

Please note that it can take up to 30 seconds for your updated functions to propagate.
Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fir-functions-22d02/overview

**I have tried the following:**

```
- Deleting "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint".  

- Deleting complete "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
```

Replaced the code with following:

```
-  {
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix ./functions/ run lint"
      "npm --prefix ./functions/ run build"
    ]
  }
}

- {
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix ./functions/ run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

None of them worked.

Comment: Most likely your functions are not recognized as HTTP-triggered functions. Add the minimal code to your question (there's an edit link under it) if you want help in troubleshooting why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just deleted the comments from the code and deployed it again. It worked!

Here is the **output**:

> functions@ lint D:\IOT\DialogFlow\firebase functions\functions
>   eslint .

- functions: Finished running predeploy script.
  i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
- functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
  i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
  i  functions: packaged functions (53.58 KB) for uploading
- functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
  i  functions: creating Node.js 6 function helloWorld(us-central1)...
  i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function helloWorldTwo(us-central1)...

The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local
source code:
        helloWorldOne(us-central1)

If you are renaming a function or changing its region, it is recommended that you create the new function first before deleting the old one to prevent event loss. For more info, visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify

? Would you like to proceed with deletion? Selecting no will continue the rest o
f the deployments. Yes
i  functions: deleting function helloWorldOne(us-central1)...
+  functions[helloWorldOne(us-central1)]: Successful delete operation.
+  functions[helloWorld(us-central1)]: Successful create operation.
Function URL (helloWorld): https://us-central1-fir-functions-28de9.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld
+  functions[helloWorldTwo(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.

- Deploy complete!

Please note that it can take up to 30 seconds for your updated functions to propagate.
Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fir-functions-28de9/overview